# How do I select values at 1 minute interval from data at 1 second interval in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a set of data recorded at a 1 second interval as below:

[image]

How can I select values at a 1 minute interval?  For example,only copying the data that recorded at xx:xx:00, which would be at a one min interval.

Comment: The approach you suggest would disregard most of your data.  There are other ways, such as aggregating the data in one minute segments (using an average by minute), or "pairing" second values, so you would treat the data like 1st second, 2nd second, etc. to produce groups of 1 minute intervals.  Just wanted to confirm that what you're asking for is specifically what you need rather than something you settled for because it was a method you thought of to accomplish it (either using it as an example to illustrate what you mean by the 1 minute interval, or didn't think of an alternate approach).

Comment: tried MINUTE() ?